# Starting service before binding to it

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I want to use `Service` in such way: first I start the service using `startService()` method. `OnStartCommand()` method returns `START_REDELIVER_INTENT`. Then (immediately or not) I bind to this service.

1) Can I be sure that the `onStartCommand()` is called on the service before calling `onBind()`?

2) When service got killed and I bind to it - will it be first restarted with the last delivered Intent (due to `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` flag) before calling `onBind()`?

Answer (score 1):

1. `onStartCommand()` should be called whenever the activity is started when it is started using `startService` or if it isn't running and it is started when `onBind()` is called but `onStartCommand()` isn't called.
2. If you return `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` the service is scheduled for restart as soon as it can be started again.

If you only want the service to run when you are interacting with it if you only use `onBind()` and don't use `startService()` then the service will be started if necessary and will be destroyed when you `unBind()`.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html for lots of good information about using services.

Comment: 1) The thing is I want the service to be restarted with the intent I provided to ```startService()``` method. I'm not happy with just ANY call to ```onStartCommand()```.

And btw it's not true that ```onStartCommand()``` is called when I bind to a service (if that's what you meant).

2) This snippet from docs still doesn't make clear (for me) what happens when I bind to the service while it is scheduled for restart - is there some sort of queue where the restart request lives, and my bind request is appended to the end of this queue?

Comment: 1) Your right about onStartCommand().  I was thinking of onCreate() and also onServiceConnected() should both be called if you bind and the service isn't started.  2) Not sure about the internal implementation but if you call onBind() multiple times you don't start the service multiple times.  I think it is guaranteed that your only going to get one instance of your service. If you call bind() when its scheduled for restart you should get the intent redelivered, the service started, then your bind should be handled, and your onServiceConnected() called.

Comment: "If you call bind() when its scheduled for restart you should get the intent redelivered, the service started, then your bind should be handled, and your onServiceConnected() called." - if you point me to some documentation that says that I will mark your answer as correct (I failed to find such information, that's why I asked question here).

Comment: The closest thing I can find to documentation to answer your question is http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_REDELIVER_INTENT .  I would think that a call to onBind() counts as a pending event.